# Pandas add column from list with bigger index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that only has 1 row:

```
TotalCount                 Percentage
57                              34
```

List1:

```
['Group1','Group2','Group3','Group4']
```

I have a list which contains 4 values. I want to add another column to my dataframe which contains the list:.

Desired Output:

```
TotalCount                 Percentage               Group
57                              34                  Group1
                                                    Group2
                                                    Group3
                                                    Group4
```

I have tried `pd.Series(List1)` but it only gives me 1 result

and if I try `df['Group'] = List1` I get Length of values (4) does not match of length of index (1)

I want to be able to add the list to the DataFrame in a new column and ignore the index

Comment: Can you include more code? Particularly the dataframe and list, and explain a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish. You don't have a 'Group' column but you're assigning it via 'Group' may things are unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 57}, 'b': {0: 34}})
Group = ['Group1','Group2','Group3','Group4']
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(Group),df], axis=1)
```

`df` being your dataframe and `Group` being your list.

Comment: To get the requested order and column names `pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(Group, columns=["Group"])], axis=1)`

Comment: I was just typing the question on how to assign it to a column name. Thanks @crayxt